# discord.py bot stops changing voice-channel names after 3 times

Tags: python, discord.py

I have coded a discord bot with discord.py, it can basically create Vcs and deletes them after no one is in them anymore. Also users can change the name of the channel with an extra text-channel created for the vc they are in. The thing is tho, after 3 times of changing it, the code breaks right at the `await channel.edit(name = newchannelname)` and stops completely. I checked and everything is working up to that point, so all of my mechanisms of finding the right channel and everything with the name, all is working. Does aynone know what the problem could be?
I´m hosting the bot on replit.com

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be an undocumented Discord API limit for editing channels, [as documented in this 2020 GitHub issue](https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/issues/1900):

> There appears to be an entirely undocumented (and unreported in the API) rate limit of 2 channel renames/10 minutes. The first two name changes go through fine, ...

Probably not a coincidence that it also caps at two, unless there's a separate error message you haven't specified or you can identify another piece of code creating the issue within the function that isn't related to API calls.

Most likely, you will have to figure out an alternate solution that doesn't rely on that specific API call: perhaps specifying the channel name at initialization or a separate optional command that must be run before the channel creation?

Comment: Thank you so much, that has to be it!